# Pandas cannot be imported for multiple mod_wsgi apps on the same server

Tags: python, pandas, mod-wsgi, python-venv

I like to have multiple instances of the same wsgi app running on an apache/mod_wsgi server. The Apps are configured by two .conf files in conf-available / conf.enabled. The first app runs fine, the second (not tried the third until now) fails with the following error (from /var/log/apache/error.log):

- ImportError: Interpreter change detected - this module can only be loaded into one interpreter per process.
- During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
- ...
- ImportError: C extension: Interpreter change detected - this module can only be loaded into one interpreter per process. not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.

My .conf files look the same just with My_App1 changing for each:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess My_App1 python-home=/var/wsgi/My_App1/venv
WSGIProcessGroup My_App1
WSGIScriptAlias /MyApp1 /var/wsgi/My_App1/odmf.wsgi
<Directory /var/wsgi/My_App1>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I am still a beginner to apache2/mod_wsgi, but I understand the WSGIProcessGroup directive, that I am starting a different processes for each App. How can pandas know to be run in multiple instances? I am using `venv` for virtual environments. Since in a later step, the apps might be running in different versions, using some kind of different environments is necessary. However, I get the same errors when I try to use the same environment for both apps.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

```
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1c mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem (just with lxml etree) with mod_wsgi/django and apache.

I have multiple django apps running via vhosts in apache, with each app running in its own mod_wsgi daemon process (not sharing anything).

Here is how i solved it:

wsgi.py (in the django app), the commented line was the auto generated one

```
# os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'theapp.settings')
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "theapp.settings"
```

apache conf

```
WSGIDaemonProcess My_App1 processes=2 threads=15 lang='C.UTF-8' locale='C.UTF-8' display-name=myapp1 python-home=/var/wsgi/My_App1/venv python-path=/path/to/My_App1
WSGIProcessGroup My_App1
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIScriptAlias /MyApp1 /var/wsgi/My_App1/odmf.wsgi process-group=My_App1
<Directory /var/wsgi/My_App1>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```